# ASP.NET MVC: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, exception

The error occurs when I create a fresh new ASP.NET MVC web application project. After running it, clicking on Register, filling in my e-mail and password and clicking the Register button - *bam* exception:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.
>   )

Seems like there's some problem creating the database. Weird thing is, this doesn't work on my laptop, but it does on my desktop computer. Ideas?

Comment: Does the LocalDB as identified in the web.config file exist?

Comment: Well, that's what I'm trying to do - to create it. You know how when the DB isn't created and you go on to register a user, then the DB gets created automatically? That's what I'm trying to do.